# In unp2 book, why there is overflow in Posix shm example?

Tags: c, linux

I don't quite understand the code below. Why is there an overflow and why is `sem_trywait()` used? Can't I just repeatedly check the semaphore by spinning `while(sem_trywait(&ptr->nempty) == -1 && errno==EAGAIN);`?

Thanks,
Jeff

**server2.c:**

```
#include        "cliserv2.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        int             fd, index, lastnoverflow, temp;
        long    offset;
        struct shmstruct        *ptr;
        char* addr;
        if (argc != 2)
                err_quit("usage: server2 <name>");

                /* 4create shm, set its size, map it, close descriptor */
        shm_unlink(Px_ipc_name(argv[1]));               /* OK if this fails */
        addr =Px_ipc_name(argv[1]);
        fd = Shm_open(addr, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, FILE_MODE);
        ptr = Mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct shmstruct), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                           MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        Ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct shmstruct));
        Close(fd);

                /* 4initialize the array of offsets */
        for (index = 0; index < NMESG; index++)
                ptr->msgoff[index] = index * MESGSIZE;

                /* 4initialize the semaphores in shared memory */
        Sem_init(&ptr->mutex, 1, 1);
        Sem_init(&ptr->nempty, 1, NMESG);
        Sem_init(&ptr->nstored, 1, 0);
        Sem_init(&ptr->noverflowmutex, 1, 1);

                /* 4this program is the consumer */
        index = 0;
        lastnoverflow = 0;
        for ( ; ; ) {
                Sem_wait(&ptr->nstored);
                Sem_wait(&ptr->mutex);
                offset = ptr->msgoff[index];
                printf("index = %d: %s\n", index, &ptr->msgdata[offset]);
                if (++index >= NMESG)
                        index = 0;                              /* circular buffer */
                Sem_post(&ptr->mutex);
                Sem_post(&ptr->nempty);

                Sem_wait(&ptr->noverflowmutex);
                temp = ptr->noverflow;          /* don't printf while mutex held */
                Sem_post(&ptr->noverflowmutex);
                if (temp != lastnoverflow) {
                        printf("noverflow = %d\n", temp);
                        lastnoverflow = temp;
                }
        }

        exit(0);
}
```

**client2.c:**

```
#include        "cliserv2.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        int             fd, i, nloop, nusec;
        pid_t   pid;
        char    mesg[MESGSIZE];
        long    offset;
        struct shmstruct        *ptr;

        if (argc != 4)
                err_quit("usage: client2 <name> <#loops> <#usec>");
        nloop = atoi(argv[2]);
        nusec = atoi(argv[3]);

                /* 4open and map shared memory that server must create */
        fd = Shm_open(Px_ipc_name(argv[1]), O_RDWR, FILE_MODE);
        ptr = Mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct shmstruct), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                           MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        Close(fd);

        pid = getpid();
        for (i = 0; i < nloop; i++) {   
                Sleep_us(nusec);
                snprintf(mesg, MESGSIZE, "pid %ld: message %d", (long) pid, i);
                if (sem_trywait(&ptr->nempty) == -1) {
                        if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                                Sem_wait(&ptr->noverflowmutex);
                                ptr->noverflow++;
                                Sem_post(&ptr->noverflowmutex);
                                continue; 
                        } else
                                err_sys("sem_trywait error");
                }
                Sem_wait(&ptr->mutex);
                offset = ptr->msgoff[ptr->nput];
                if (++(ptr->nput) >= NMESG)
                        ptr->nput = 0;          /* circular buffer */
                Sem_post(&ptr->mutex);
                strcpy(&ptr->msgdata[offset], mesg);
                Sem_post(&ptr->nstored);
        }
        msync(ptr, sizeof(struct shmstruct), MS_SYNC);
        munmap(ptr, sizeof(struct shmstruct));
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It helps if you say the chapter you are studying.

Answer (score 4):

In 13.6, the book explains the use of the overflow counter:

> **Overflow counter**
>
> The possibility exists that a client
>   wants to send a message but all the
>   message slots are taken. But if the
>   client is actually a server of some
>   type (perhaps an FTP server or an HTTP
>   server), the client does not want to
>   wait for the server to free up a slot.
>   Therefore, we will write our clients
>   so that they do not block but
>   increment the `noverflow` counter when
>   this happens. (...)

So, the reason is that the client should never block, even in case it can't send the message. Spinning, like you suggested, is no better than simply using `sem_wait()` directly, which was already covered earlier in the book. The author just demonstrated how to handle a different situation, where blocking is not wanted.

Comment: "Blocking is not wanted" for client is the key. Thanks you all.

Comment: @Jeff since you are new here: If the answer resolves your problem, you should mark it as answered by clicking on the green checkmark on the left margin of the answer.